# Showing a list of posts when homepage is custom

Tags: theme-development, homepage, blog, home-url

I am developing a custom theme.

I edited my home.php to show something custom. I also edited index.php to display a list of posts or other things.

After this I can't get a list of all posts which was by default displayed at the home page.

Which URL can I use to access the list of posts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to [familiarize yourself with the WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), so that you ensure that you are modifying the appropriate template file:

- **Home**: *Blog Posts Index* page; template file: `home.php`
- **Front Page**: *Site Front Page*; template file: `front-page.php`

I am assuming that you want to display a **static front page**, and to *display your blog posts index on a separate page*? If so:

1. Use the `front-page.php` template file to define the custom front-page markup
2. Use the `home.php` template file to define the markup for your blog posts index (or, omit entirely, and let the blog posts index simply fall back to `index.php`)
3. Create **two** static pages: one as the site front page placeholder, and one as the blog posts index placeholder
4. Set `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading` appropriately

Comment: 1. I do not use static pages. 2. I renamed home.php into front-page.php as you suggested. (I now have no home.php as it uses index.php). But my issue is not solved, I don't know how to display (what URL should I type in a browser) the list of all posts. Please help.

Comment: Did you follow steps 3 and 4 above? You **need** to be using static pages, if you are outputting anything *other* than your Blog Posts Index on your site front page.

Answer (score -4):

If you want a global recent posts list you need to create a loop
that would show them if you want to show them in your home.php 
you can use this code where you want.. (no inside the loop)

```
// The Query
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC'
)
query_posts( $args );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title().'<br />';
    the_excerpt().'<br />';
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query 
wp_reset_query();
```

.
i have left the amount of posts shown there so you can control it...
Additional arguments you can use to refine the loop can be found at
[WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) in the wordpress codex...

**Hope this Helps ;)

Sagive.**

.

*(p.s: 0% accept rate which is what you have is not ok.. you should go back to the question you asked and either answer them yourself or pick the correct answer if exist and approve it... It best for the community)*

Comment: The `home.php` template file is intended for output of the **Blog Posts Index**, and should **not** be used to define custom front-page markup. Use `front-page.php` for this purpose.

Comment: The way i see it is that you can define a query wherever you want.. no such thing "Meant to" - thats the great thing about wordpress

Comment: Uh, yes, there **is** such a thing as *meant to*. In fact, *meant to* is the **entire purpose of the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)**. If you conflate `home.php` and `front-page.php`, and use `home.php` to output custom static front page content when `home.php` is ***meant to*** output the blog posts index, *things **WILL** break*.

Comment: i have built many homepages where is have static content and a mini loop showing whats new somewhere on page... i considre it to be much more dynamic from an seo point of view. lets agree to dissagree ;)

Comment: No, sorry; can't "agree to disagree" on this one. Your scenario only works if/when the *Blog Posts Index is not output on a separate page when using a static front page*. This scenario is an edge case for any site that actually uses blog posts.

Comment: i actually think its far more common then a completly static homepage... but i dont want to argue inside this in this answer.. chat? (i am inside StopPress)

Comment: What you output on the site front page is largely irrelevant - even if that output includes a custom query to display latest posts. Even in that scenario, if you use `home.php` to output this content, you will then be unable to display the blog posts index properly, anywhere.